# How to update a column value with ROW_NUMBER() OVER value based on distinct values of a column

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions, row-number

I have one table, in which I want to update the value for a particular column. The column value should be row number. Based on a column distinct value I need to update the newly created column value.

Example:

Contents of `INFO_T` table:

```
Name   | id 
------------
Arijit | 120
Suman  | 240
Priyam | 555
Arijit | 456
Suvayu | 110
Priyam | 300
```

I need to add one more column within the above table `INFO_T`, below is the example. I have to use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER` function, through which I have to update that `SEQ_NO` column.

```
Name   | id  | Seq_no
------------------
Arijit | 120 | 1
Suman  | 240 | 2
Priyam | 555 | 3
Arijit | 120 | 1
Suvayu | 110 | 4
Priyam | 555 | 3
```

How to get that above result?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Please can you explain how you would allocate the sequence number to get your result? For example, order all the rows by Name ascending order, then apply the Row_number over distinct instances of each name? OR order all the rows by ID ascending order, then apply the Row_number over distinct instances of each name? I don't see how you have done it as it doesnt seem alphabetical nor does it seem related to the id.

Comment: I have used Oracle SQL Developer. Sorry for the previous info. I have updated it. Please check once.

Comment: I cant get the exact output as you want, because rownum() put the SEQ id ordering by name first. Is that a problem?  you can comment in my answer

Comment: If I used distinct  keyword to the name column then the value should be distinct. After doing this if I put the seq_no using that row_number() function then the column have unique id.

Comment: @diziaq: please do not tag SQL questions with `analytics` if the mention Oracle's "analytical functions". Those functions are called "window functions" in SQL and the tag `window-functions` should be used for them. `analytics` is a different topic (please read the tag info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dense_rank()` for this purpose:

```
select name, id, dense_rank() over (order by minid) as seqno
from (select t.*, min(id) over (partition by name) as minid
      from table t
     ) t;
```

If you wanted to do this just with `row_number()`:

```
select t.name, t.id, tt.seqnum
from table t join
     (select t.name, row_number() over (order by min(id)) as seqno
      from table t
      group by t.name
     ) tt
     on t.name = tt.name;
```

However, I don't know why you would want to do that.

Comment: Hello Gordon, on second select should be `tt.seqno`. Also I dont think would matter, but in my query and yours the `rownumber()` sort by name so I can't get the exact output as OP. Do you know how fix it? You can see my fiddle.

Comment: i think cant be done, because sql doesnt guarantees any sort unless you use `ORDER BY`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . There needs to be a column in the data that specifies the ordering.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a1f07/9)

```
SELECT Table1.name, Table1.ID, SEQ.Seq_no
FROM 
    (SELECT name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by name) as Seq_no
     FROM (SELECT  DISTINCT name FROM Table1) as unique_name ) as SEQ INNER JOIN
     Table1 on SEQ.name = Table1.Name
```

Comment: Not only does it not answer the question, it don't provide the correct  numbers.

Comment: @ZoharPeled fix it now

Comment: not really. you better look at the results of the fiddle before posting the answer....

Comment: @ZoharPeled I think is ok, Each name have an uniqueID. I cant get the exact output as OP require because SQL doesnt guarantees a sort unless you use `ORDER BY`. If you still see something wrong please let me know and I try to fix it.

Comment: Hi Juan,
I want the update query to insert the seq_no. could you please help me.

Comment: no problem, but i need more details. First this solve your issue? Then your question is do you have an aditional empty column on info_t and want update with this query??

Answer (score 0):

This is MS SQL, but it looks like Row_Number functions the same in Oracle.  If you can't do a CTE (WITH) statement, these could be done as sub-queries instead.  Maybe someone with Oracle SQL experience could use this example and re-write it.  I can't guarantee the results, since they are unordered, but basically I first create a RowID, without order, from the table.  This allowed me to ensure the names were in the same order you have them in (which seems to be insert order).  Then I essentially did sub-queries of that to get the FIRST distinct instance of each name in order.  Then I joined back to the original table.  Here it is in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b28679/71/0).

```
;WITH NoOrderBy AS
(
  select Row_Number() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) RowID,Name,id
  FROM MyTable
),
DistinctNames  AS
(
  SELECT Row_Number() OVER(ORDER BY RowID) RowID3,Name,RowID,id
  FROM
  (
    SELECT Row_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY RowID) RowID2,Name,RowID,id
    FROM NoOrderBy
   ) a
   WHERE RowID2 = 1
)
SELECT mt.Name,di.id,di.RowID3 Seq_no 
FROM MyTable mt
INNER JOIN DistinctNames di
ON mt.Name =di.Name
```